# How to recreate something like std.conv.to in D?

Tags: templates, d

I've got a manager for Assets for a simple game in D, and I wanted to make a simple *get* function so that *get!Texture(...)* or *get!Sound(...)* would be an option. I'm fairly new to templates and this didn't work out so well when I tried it:

```
T get(T) (string p_name)
{
    if (T is Texture)
        return _textures[p_name];
    else if (T is Sound)
        return _sounds[p_name];
    else if (...)
            ...
    else 
        return null;
}
```

First of all, this didn't compile because after the first return statement, it seems to only accept returns of Texture. Second, I'm not a big fan of the list of if statements -- is there a better way to go about doing this? I know *std.conv.to* managed it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
T get(T) (string p_name)
{
    static if (is(T : Texture))
        return _textures[p_name];
    else static if (is(T : Sound))
        return _sounds[p_name];
    else static if (...)
            ...
    else 
        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you'll want to use static if:

```
T get(T) (string p_name)
{
    static if (is(T == Texture))
        return _textures[p_name];
    else if (is(T == Sound))
        return _sounds[p_name];
    else if (...)
            ...
    else 
        return null;
}
```

or template constraint

```
T get(T) (string p_name) if (is(T == Texture)){
    return _textures[p_name];
}
T get(T) (string p_name) if (is(T == Sound)){
    return _sounds[p_name];
}
T get(T) (string p_name) if (is(T ==  ...)){
    return ...;
}
T get(T) (string p_name)
    return null;
}
```

Either way the [source of std.conv](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/blob/master/std/conv.d) is available for inspection (where they used a combination of the two).

Comment: The correct term is "template constraint" rather than "template clause," unless mean something by "template clause" other than the `if` on the template, in which case I don't know what you're referring to.

Comment: When I use the template constraint method, I get the error "Cannot interpret Texture at compile time." What would cause this?

Comment: The template constraint syntax should be `if (is(T : Texture))`

Comment: @ratchetfreak The `static if`s need the same change, and it's usually better to use `is(T == Type)` rather than `is(T : Type)`, as implicit conversions can cause issues, and in this particular case, `T : Type` is actually an implicit conversion in the wrong direction, since you're returning a `T`, not a `Type`, and `Type` doesn't necessarily implicitly convert to `T` (and probably doesn't if `Type` actually `T`, since implicit conversions often don't go in both directions).